# How to apply rotation and scale, avoiding shifting of the vertex parented objects?

Tags: modeling, vertices, geometry, parent

In my scene I have a lot of elements that are connected to each other via the vertex parenting. I forgot to apply rotation and scale to those elements, but it is necessary so that I could correctly export them. Now, if I apply the rotation and scale, all the elements shift in different directions.

Is there a way apply rotation and scale so that I don't have to manually move each of these elements in the right place?

Comment: As a workaround you could copy values of scaling in Object mode, clear scale and in Edit mode scale the model back (you can paste the value using `Ctrl`+`V` just after activating `S` tool). The same should work for rotation.

Comment: @MrZak Unfortunately, in my case it did not work out. Maybe I made a mistake? Here's an example: I have selected a rope in the object mode and copied value of the Scale X: http://postimg.org/image/8vv3o91jz/

Comment: @MrZak Then I applyed roation and scale, and objects that are attached to the rope via the vertex parent, as well as objects attached to them, become shifted: http://postimg.org/image/46my0obaf/

Comment: @MrZak Then I switched to the edit mode, select vertices of the rope, pressed "S" and then Ctrl + V, and the proportion of the rope become distorted. I tried to press "X" after pressing "S" (because I copied Scale X parameter), and then press Ctrl + V, but the result is the same: http://postimg.org/image/6qbvpqlqt/

Comment: @MrZak Why is this happening?
Probably in my case, the objects are shifting, because, somehow, I disrupted vertex parenting, so an object, to which I am applying rotation and scale is remains at the same place and with the same proportions, while other objects, connected to it - shifts. In this case, why do applying rotation and scale disrupting parenting, and how can I fix it? Or maybe there's a quick way to return the shifted objects to their original place?

Comment: "Then I applyed roation and scale" Did you try to *clear* rotation and scale and *then* proceed to scaling in Edit mode? See [wiki for more info on this operation](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/reset_object_transformations.html?highlight=applying%20transforms). Of course this is a workaround and it's hard to tell how it may work without .blend. Can you provide a simplified version?

Comment: @MrZak Thank you for the link! Of course, thank you, here is the blend file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/39628 This scene includes the rope, the wind, the cloth on the rope, and two clothespins. A clothespin made of of three objects (two "legs" and a spring), I move them using parenting to an empty object (which is vertex parented to the cloth).

Comment: @MrZak I found a way that allows to leave things remain in their places - unparent them via CTRL + A - "clear and keep transformation", then applying rotation and scale, and then parent objects to each other again. In this case, the objects do not move, and I don't need to move all of them in their original locations.

Comment: @MrZak However when I am applying rotation and scale to the clothespins, they slightly change their position and rotation, and normals of one "leg" becoming  inverted. You can select the clothespin and apply rotation and scale, to understand what I mean. The same thing happens if I clear rotation or scale, and if I clear location - clothespin greatly shifting to a different location.

Comment: @MrZak It would not be a big problem - after applying rotation and scale, clothespin shifted quite a bit and I can easily bring it back into the correct position, but I still have a problem with baking cloth animation , as well as, unexpectedly - with baking  clothespins animation! I tried to bake it's animation from the side menu (T), but one "leg" of the clothespins strongly shifts. Now I'm trying to solve this problem.

I think if we will solve those problems - it will be an interesting experience for others. Thank you for your help ones again!

Comment: You could recreate the rope modeling a curve of that shape, giving it thickness and applying transforms to it, then using parenting. You sholdn't clear location - it will be set up to 0,0,0 (default one) which isn't what you want afaik. I can't tell you anything about clothespins though - their normals didn't become inverted for me, but anyway you should recalculate them before proceeding to animation (wasn't that one which strongly shifts as you said?).

Comment: @MrZak How can I recalculate them?
I described my problems with applying rotation and scale, and, first of all - with baking animation of the scene here:  http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?387794-How-to-transfer-Blender-scene-with-cloth-simulation-to-Maya-and-Houdini&p=2980553#post2980553 
I summed up everything in my last three posts (starting from the post №10). There I also added screenshots with description. I need to send this work as soon as possible, and I would be very glad to your advice.